# custom table left join with catalog/product

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection, catalog, eav

I have a custom table called `flagged_products` which lists flagged products like this:

```
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| entity_id | product_id |     flagged_on      |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|         1 |     356534 | 2019-03-01 12:45:20 |
|         2 |     654657 | 2019-01-07 05:52:09 |
|         3 |     345477 | 2019-03-23 09:34:07 |
|         4 |     114673 | 2019-04-11 15:45:17 |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

I want to join this with the catalog/product model to list all the names of the products which have been flagged like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
| entity_id | product_name |     flagged_on      |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|    356534 | Product 1    | 2019-03-01 12:45:20 |
|    654657 | Product 2    | 2019-01-07 05:52:09 |
|    345477 | Product 3    | 2019-03-23 09:34:07 |
|    114673 | Product 4    | 2019-04-11 15:45:17 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

However, since the product name is a part of the EAV tables, i'm not really sure how to get this information.

Would appreciate help on how this can be achieved with Magento 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try the "Magento way", you could try something like :

```
$flaggedProducts = Mage::getModel('your_module/your_model')->getCollection();
// Join with product table
$flaggedProducts->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('cp' => $flaggedProducts->getTable('catalog/product'),
        'cp.entity_id=main_table.product_id',
        array(
            'product_entity_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('cp.entity_id')
        )
    );
// Join to get the name
    $nameAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'name');
    $nameTable = $nameAttribute->getBackendTable();
    $nameId = $nameAttribute->getAttributeId();
    // Get default store name value
    $flaggedProducts->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('nt' => $nameTable),
        'nt.attribute_id=' . $nameId . ' AND nt.entity_id = cp.entity_id AND nt.store_id = 0',
        array(
            'product_name' => new Zend_Db_Expr('nt.value')
        )
    );
```

If you just want to do some sql query, maybe something like :

```
SELECT fp.*, cpev_name.value FROM  flagged_products AS fp
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev_name
             ON fp.product_id = cpev_name.entity_id AND cpev_name.attribute_id = 'put-here-the-id-of-the-attribute-name' 
AND cpev_name.store_id = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query it will give you expected output.

```
select fp.*, cpev.value as product_name from flagged_products as fp
left JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar as cpev on cpev.entity_id = fp.product_id
WHERE cpev.attribute_id=71
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('flagged_products' => $this->getTable('flagged_products')),
        'e.entity_id = flagged_products.product_id'
    );
```

Comment: I want the `flagged_products` table to be on the left.

Comment: Code updated, please check